# Slicing a dictionary of list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary of lists, each list greater than 50 items, and to simplify, lets say the dictionary keys are ['a','b','c']. I spend way to long trying to figure out a very pythonic was to sort and slice these lists. What I have so far:

```
dict = dictionary_of_lists under discussion
[dict[k].sort(reverse=True) for k in dict.keys()]
for k, l in dict.items():
    slice = 10 if k in ('a','c') else 20
    dict[k] = l[:slice]
```

I end up with a sorted, and trimmed up list, just like I want. But what I wanted was a one line piece of code like `[dict[k].sort(reverse=True) for k in dict.keys()]` when I slice against the sorted list. And if someone can figure out how to put the sorting and slicing together, they would be my hero.

UPDATE: First, I like being able to ask somewhat complex questions because they help me learn better coding skills (since I am self taught). So thanks everyone below! My new code:

```
for c in list_of_categories:
    list = [getattr(p,c.name) for p in people if hasattr(p,c.name)]
    slice = c.get_slice_value # I added an @property function to a class named `Category`
    c.total = sum(sorted(list, reverse=True)[:slice])
```

Comment: Very pythonic != one-line piece of code.  Often they're almost opposites.  There's always [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/index.html)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions with side effects are usually considered bad style. Create a new dict instead:

```
dct = {k: sorted(l, reverse=True)[:10 if k in ('a','c') else 20] 
    for k, l in dct.items()}
```

Also slice values look arbitrary at the moment, it might be better to configure them separately, for example:

```
slices = {
    'a': 10,
    'b': 10,
    'c': 20
}    

dct = {k: sorted(l, reverse=True)[:slices[k]] 
    for k, l in dct.items()}
```

Comment: Why bad style? Readibility?

Comment: Your comment helped me a) realize I had overthought the problem, and b) write a sliver of code which was both better and more readable.

Comment: @Cole: in python, you usually either modify a value (like `sort`, `list.append`) or return a new value (like `sorted`, `list+list`). A LH with side effects attempts to do both, and this is mostly a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

`sort()` works in place, affecting each list. You'd want to create new ones:

```
[sorted(d[k], reverse = True)[:10 if k in ('a','c') else 20] for k in d.keys()]
```

Note that it's not very readable.